# onKeyDown / onBackPressed is not firing

Tags: android, back, onkeydown, activitygroup, pressed

In which cases are onKeyDown, onBackPressed not firing?

In my case I have a TabActivity with a ActivityGroup in background where all the upcoming views/activities are stored. The ActivityGroup takes care of adding and removing views. So when I start a new Activity in my main tab the startChildActivity method of ActivityGroup is called:

```
public void startChildActivity(String viewId, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(viewId, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if(window != null) {
        history.add(new HistoryContainer(viewId));
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

If I now start the Activity Dummy in this way the mentioned keyEvents like onKeyDown or onBackPressed are not firing anymore. What's happening is the app is closing.

```
public class Dummy extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dummy);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    MazdaGroup.group.back();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MazdaGroup.group.back();
}
```

}

Would be glad for your help!

Comment: have you tried Logging to see which event (if any) are being fired. That is where i would start

Comment: There's no event fired at all. I even tried to catch a breakpoint on dispatchKeyEvent(), but non of them are called.
LogCat just shows the usual "No keyboard for id 0" / "Using defaukt keymap: /system/..."

Comment: @flowacasa did you fix the problem? I need it to.

Comment: I finally fixed the problem, which wasn't a problem at all.
I tried to call the onBackPressed method with a parameter like "onBackPressed(1)" which couldn't work..
Just a stupid mistake, but thanks for your help!

Comment: How did u fix this issue? please help me